# How to add single nginx cache keys or file

Tags: nginx, cache, keys

How to add single nginx cache keys or file before client access link website. if link website quite more content example: html, image, video... several first access site very slow for cache server load.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

after I curl -I http://testsite.com/file.txt all content of site be come load to server cache.